# Scaling for Powerful Fist

Tags: unarmed-combat, pathfinder-2e

Given the description for [Monks](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=8)' powerful fist:

> You know how to wield your fists as deadly weapons. The damage die for your fist increases to 1d6 instead of 1d4. Most people take a –2 circumstance penalty when making a lethal attack with nonlethal unarmed attacks, because they find it hard to use their fists with deadly force. You don’t take this penalty when making a lethal attack with your fist or any other unarmed attacks.

If a barbarian or other class with a damage die higher than 1d4 multiclassed into monk and received this feat, would it increase by a single step, such as 1d6 -> 1d8, or does this not increase at all?

My group has been discussing this for several hours now, send help.

Comment: Are you referring to the special unarmed attacks that barbarians with the animal instinct get? Generally, barbarians' unarmed attacks use the same d4 damage die as all othwrs5.

Comment: @indigochild yes, but in general any unarmed attack with a higher damage dice.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The monk's Powerful Fist damage die increase refers specifically to the [fist](http://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=1) weapon. Other unarmed attacks (such as razortooth goblin jaws, animal barbarian claws and monk stance attacks) are not fists and will not benefit from it.

Comment: That's how I assumed to run it, thanks. One caveat though, is if a barbarian takes animal instinct and chooses the ape instinct, they gain a fist attack that does 1d10 damage, how does Powerful Fist apply here?

Comment: I suspect it doesn't, that Powerful Fist refers to the unarmed strike everyone has and not the barbarian unarmed strike of the same name, but I don't have a source for that.

Comment: @HowardP Well, the wording says it increases from 1d4 to 1d6. Ape instinct doesn't start at 1d4, and can't strictly increase to 1d6 (since that would be lower).